# python + tornado : 404 on imported request handler

Tags: python, tornado

im trying to build a tornado app using python. I've been able to build a basic routing system as such :

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      self.write("Default endpoint.")

class CountHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      self.write("Count endpoint.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   application = tornado.web.Application([
      (r"/", MainHandler),
      (r"/count", CountHandler),
  ])
  application.listen(8888)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

What i want to achieve is to import those handler class ( from a specific `handlers` folder ) instead of defining them in this file ( they might get bigger ). To do so i've extracted my `CountHandler` class into it's own separate file and i'm importing it as such :

```
from handlers import CountHandler

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      self.write("Default endpoint.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   application = tornado.web.Application([
      (r"/", MainHandler),
      (r"/count", CountHandler),
  ])
  application.listen(8888)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

the `CountHandler` class haven't changed a bit, but now i'm getting 404 on my `/count` endpoint. Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: It should work. The problem must be somewhere else. Does your `handlers` folder have a file called `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it !

In my import, i import the whole `CountHandler` lib. Therefore if i want to use the class `CountHandler` in my code it should be `CountHandler.CountHandler` ( `ImportedLib.Myclass` )